# How to Update the Model in MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a Markdown editor in my MVC 5 application.Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var executivesummary = new tui.Editor({
el: document.querySelector('#Recommendation'),
previewStyle: 'vertical'})
```

I have save function to save the contents of the editor like this

```
function saveContent(e) {
 var contents = Recommendation.GetValue();
 console.log(content)
 e.preventDefault();
                        }
```

I have a field in Model with get and set,i want to update this value "contents" to the Model. How to do this?

Comment: you mean you want to save the value to the server / database? Or you want to simply update it in the HTML page without saving? It's not totally clear. Saving it to "the model" doesn't make much sense - the model class is an ephemeral object and only exists to transfer the data from controller to view and back again. It's the structure within which to send the data, not the destination of the data. Either way, it's a common task with many possible solutions and likely lots of content online on the subject already. What did you research or try already?

Comment: @ADyson Yep! i want to update the value contained in "contents" to database.  While in other cases i would used Html helpers like this `@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.WORecommendation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`  .  Is there a way to update to the database?

Comment: probably making an ajax request and passing the value of `contents` to the server in the data would be my recommendation

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a call to an action method within your controller to update the model. Then you can reload the view (or parts of it) with Ajax (or using Ajax.BeginForm).

Some example ajax call:

```
$("#idToClickOn").click(function () {
    var contents = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Recommendation.GetValue()));
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://@(Request.Url.Host)/Controller/Action',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: contents,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
        error: function (data) {
            alert("error: " + data);
        }
    });
});
```

Some example with Ajax.BeginForm:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", new { Controller = "ControllerName", area = "" }, new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "onSuccessLogin", HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "idInViewToUpdate"}, new { id = "formID" }))
{
    ...
    <div>
        @Html.Partial("Path to form body")                           
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Save</button>
}
```

Your controller, something like:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HandleError]
public ActionResult Action(YourModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        do Something;
        return PartialView("Path to your view");
    }
    else
    {
        return PartialView("Path to your view", model);
    }
}
```

YourModel needs to fit the json you create, of course.

In that action, you can modify the model and reload the view.